# postgres14 trims digits in timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 14. I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS F_WALLET
(
    id                      serial PRIMARY KEY,
    // columns
    // more columns
    inserttime              timestamp
);
```

I have python code that does insert, example:

```
INSERT INTO F_WALLET
    (
    // some more columns
    inserttime
    )
    VALUES (
          11.05,      137.66,        2.20,
         137.66,        0.00,       21.81,
           0.00,       21.81,      115.85,
         137.66,        0.00,      115.85,
           true, '2022-09-15 2022-09-15 20:21:57.768330+02:00' 
    )
```

But if microseconds in inserttime (last column) end with zeros it gets trimmed..
Now (using pgadmin/console/any other tool) when I do `SELECT id, inserttime FROM F_WALLET` I have:

```
 897  | 2022-09-15 20:22:05.400541 
 896  | 2022-09-15 20:22:03.477851 
 895  | 2022-09-15 20:22:01.9936   
 894  | 2022-09-15 20:22:00.591512 
 893  | 2022-09-15 20:21:57.76833  
 892  | 2022-09-15 20:21:54.860594
```

How do I force my table to put zeros to get exactly n-digits ?
If not possible then how do I force my select to add zeroes to have exactly n-digits in microseconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps have no format. Queries *present* them as needed. You may use  [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to explicitly format the timestamp like this:

```sql
SELECT id, 
    to_char(inserttime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.us') as inserttime
FROM F_WALLET;
```

or `format` and `extract` in more complex cases.